# What are the most common (usual) ways to make palettes with non-trivial functionality?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, palettes, guidelines

What are the best (most robust and most convenient) ways to create palettes that can be installed permanently (using `Palettes -> Install Palette...`) and are safe to use?  I'd be interested in how other people have done this in the past to learn more about idiomatic front end programming.

I put some code illustrating the pattern I am using now at the end of this post.  I'd appreciate some comments on it.

**Notes and requirements:**

1. The palette should always work, regardless of whether the kernel has been quit or an evaluation is running.
2. The palette may have more than one button which share some code between them.
3. It must not pollute the `` Global` `` context or change the kernel state in a way that might break something unexpectedly.
4. I'm looking for an easy way to define palettes (minimal boilerplate code and extra work)
5. It would be nice (non-essential) if several versions of the palette could coexist independently (my current approach doesn't have this because it uses its own context to hide its function definition, but everything in this context is shared)
6. It would also be nice (non-essential) to integrate documentation in an easy way (help button bringing it up maybe?)

---

My current approach is illustrated below.  It "localizes" its symbols by putting them in a separate context, and uses `DynamicModule` to ensure that all the definitions are done before any button code is run.

```
SetAttributes[paletteButton, HoldAll]
paletteButton[name_, tooltip_, func_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Tooltip[Button[name, Unevaluated[func], Appearance -> "Palette", 
   opt], tooltip, TooltipDelay -> Automatic]

Begin["SomePalette`"];

PaletteNotebook[
 DynamicModule[{},
  Column[{
    paletteButton["One", "Button one", function[1]],
    paletteButton["Two", "Button two", function[2]]
    }],

  Initialization :> (
    function[x_] := MessageDialog[x]
    )
  ],
 WindowTitle -> "Some Palette"
 ]

End[];
```

Comment: BTW I always found it odd that you there isn't an 'uninstall palette' menu item.

Comment: @Sjoerd It's more difficult to implement, but I agree, it should be present.  Palettes usually go into `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "Palettes"}]`

Comment: Note: this is a question asking about "best-practices" / "what is idiomatic" and what different ways are there to achieve this.  I already have a solution which satisfies most requirements I have, but it would be tremendously helpful to at least hear from others who have made palettes in the past.  I am not sure if these types of questions will be welcome on the site or not.

Comment: I saw the title of this question and thought: "This sounds like a good question for Szabolcs!"  I think I learned about non-trivial palettes from your web site. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately not.  I only made that simple little TablePaste palette because I was tired of importing data from website table manually.  But as you can see the code is even included three times in that one (so ugly!)  I didn't know anything about making palettes properly, I'm just learning now

Comment: I like your question and appreciate all the answers you have provided, but can you explain why you think that uninstall is difficult to implement? It would just mean to close all instances and remove the file. Doesn't sound like rocket science to me (and I have done it for my own palettes and packages, so there is no guessing about what needs to be done)...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All palette state (i.e., variables which affect the palette and should be remembered between sessions) should be vectored through the palette's `TaggingRules` option, and its initialization should be done in the palette's `NotebookDynamicExpression` option.  That, plus context isolation of any kernel functions you need to define should solve all of the points you raise, excepting the documentation issue.

An example palette which demonstrates these principles:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[{Button["Print opener state", 
    MyPalette`Private`DoSomething[
     "The opener is " <> 
      If[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "opener"}],
        "open", "closed"]]],
   OpenerView[{"Group of buttons", Column[{Button[1], Button[2]}]}, 
    Dynamic[CurrentValue[
      EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "opener"}, False]]]}],
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> 
  Refresh[MyPalette`Private`DoSomething[MyPalette`Private`x_] := 
    Print[MyPalette`Private`x], None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's hit the items raised in this code one by one...

- The palette uses a kernel-defined function which is in `NotebookDynamicExpression`. The code is wrapped in `Refresh[_,None]` to ensure that it evaluates once only when the notebook is opened. The code is context isolated by hand. Note that `Begin` and `End` won't work here, although they would work inside of a package, or if you wrapped the code in `ToExpression` (e.g., `` Begin["foo`"];ToExpression["code"];End[] ``).
- A palette-wide state variable is stored in the palette's `TaggingRules`, which can be accessed by using `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{TaggingRules,"opener"}]`. Because "opener" is a string, no symbols are introduced into any context.
- State variables will typically need to be initialized. I could do that in various standard ways, but I used the undocumented third argument to `CurrentValue` which sets it to False if it doesn't already have a value.
- Once the palette is installed, the `TaggingRules` setting will persist between instances of the palette, even if you quit Mathematica. Mathematica automatically serializes an installed palette's `TaggingRules` settings when you close it by storing the value into the global option `PalettesMenuSettings`.
- If you have multiple versions of the palette open, they'll each operate using independent state variables because the state variable is attached to the palette notebook. If multiple versions of the palette are installed under different names then the `PalettesMenuSettings` trick will store the `TaggingRules` separately.

Comment: Again, the highlight is `TaggingRules`.  I have one concern about using `NotebookDynamicExpression` with `Refresh[..., None]` instead of the `Initialization` option of a `DynamicModule` wrapping everything: the definitions won't survive a kernel restart if we use  `Refresh[..., None]`.  Is there any reason not to use a `DynamicModule[..., Initialization :> ...]` here?  Regarding `Begin` and `End`:  I think if we evaluate `Begin["..."]` before evaluating the `CreatePalette[...]`, then evaluate `End[]` after, everything new symbol in the palette will be correctly localized into the proper...

Comment: ... context.  Is this correct?  (We just need to take care that `Begin`, `CreatePalette` and `End` are sent to the kernel as separate expressions to ensure that `Begin` will affect the parsing of `CreatePalette`).

Comment: @Szabolcs The `Initialization` option of `DynamicModule` is fine if all of the code you're initializing for is inside that `DynamicModule`. What you cannot do is to make assumptions about the order in which subsequent `DynamicModule` or `Dynamic` expressions will fire, or even if they will fire (if they're not in the same position). If `NotebookDynamicExpression` doesn't fire in new kernel sessions, it certainly should. I admit to not having tried this recently.

Comment: @Szabolcs What I meant is that you can't use `Begin` and `End` inside of `Initialization` without forcing a separate parse stage to begin, as would happen with `Get` or `ToExpression`.  Yes, you should be able to use `Begin`/`End` outside of `CreatePalette`, but *only* if they are on separate lines of input. I.e., they can't be a part of a `CompoundExpression` or other expression which contains the `CreatePalette` command. This means terminating all operators and placing a newline in the input cell, or putting the `Begin`/`End` in totally different cells.

Comment: Is it okay to store large data in TaggingRules such as 5-10 thumbnail images (of the size returned by `Thumbnail`), or is this likely to cause performance problems because the system was not designed for this?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't think thumbnail images would be too bad.  But yes, you will eventually start to get to the point where it could have an impact on startup time (i.e., when preferences are loaded).

Comment: @JohnFultz Is it possible that `NotebookDynamicExpression`s stop working when you restart the kernel, at least until you reassign them or reopen the notebook?

Comment: I hope the bug of `NotebookDynamicExpression` not firing in new kernel sessions gets fixed soon

Comment: @Rojolalalalalalalalalalalalala 2 years and counting so I suppose this answer is obsolete since one have to manually close and open a palette to triger definitions load. Not to mention that `Dynamic[DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 1]` put on top of the column here will freeze forever after kernel quit.

Answer (score 7):

You could generate the palette from code in a separate notebook, and have the generated palette use a unique context by setting `CellContext -> Notebook` when creating the palette notebook.

I think this should help with items 2, 3, and 5.

---

*Example* (there may be better ways..)

```
CreateDocument[
   {Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[x = 2]], "Input"]}, 
   CellContext -> Notebook]
```

If you then look at `Context[x]` in the created notebook, you get something like `` Notebook$$21$666892` ``

Comment: I think you should mention that this can be done with setting CellContext->Notebook for the PaletteNotebook.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Agreed, it's good to be detailed about that.

Comment: Could you give a code example?  If I simply add `CellContex -> Notebook` to `PaletteNotebook` in my example above, `function` will still be created in the ``SomePalette` `` context (or ``Global` `` if I remove `Begin`/`End`).  This is because contexts are decided at parse time.

Answer (score 5):

This is a supplementary answer to what John Fultz has provided.

### Problem 1:

The problem is that sometimes I can't include all functionality inside the palette nor I can call Needs to load it after kernel restart because the package initialization is a little bit complicated.

What I'm fine with though is to be able to close the Palette/Dialog/GUInotebook as soon as the new session starts.

#### Solution:

**Warning** - it is based on not stable behavior that `NotebookDynamicExpression` is loaded only when the notebook is opened, and not when the kernel restarts. As said in comments in accepted answer, this should not be the case. But it is for more than 3 years.

So I will abuse here the fact that `NotebookDynamicExpression` only fires when the notebook is opened while `Initialization` every time the session was terminated. So we will check if Initialization is done in the same session and we can close the notebook otherwise.

This notebook will close itself after you close the kernel (which is restarted by dynamics):

```
CreateDocument[
 DynamicModule[{},
  Dynamic[{"Date :", DateString[]}, UpdateInterval -> 1],
  Initialization :> (
    If[CurrentValue[
       EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Opened"}] =!= $SessionID,
      NotebookClose[]]
    )
  ],
 TaggingRules -> {ParentList, "Opened" -> $SessionID},
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
   CurrentValue[
     EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Opened"}] = $SessionID
   , None]
 ]
```

### Problem 2

I don't like to write full names like: `` NotebookDynamicExpression :> 
  Refresh[MyPalette`Private`DoSomething[MyPalette`Private`x_] := 
    Print[MyPalette`Private`x], None]] ``

#### Method:

You can inject the package to the palette the same way I've done this for a CDF: [**How can I include functions from a package into a CDF file?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86707/5478)

Answer (score 3):

My go-to currently is to have a template that is laid out like this:

```
BeginPackage["paletteContext`Private`"]

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Builder Initialization *)

(* define code to initialize the palette builder *)
paletteBuilderInit[]

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Options *)

(* define palette options *)

paletteOps = {  };

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Formatting Objects *)

(* define attractive formatting objects the deploy as Button or other interface elements that don't load from a package *)

defFormattingObject1[]
defFormattingObject2[]

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Functions *)

(* define helper functions for finding functions by name (not by explicit symbol lookup) and for loading the parent paclet of the palette *)

defLoadUnderlyingPaclet[]
defLoadFunctionByName[]
defOtherFuncs[]

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Elements *)

(* define a collection of palette elements *)

paletteElement1[]
paletteElement2[]
paletteElement3[]

paletteEls = { paletteElement1, spacer , ...};

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Palette Expression *)

(* 
  This could be done just as well / better with DynamicModule, 
  but that's just not how I have it currently
 *)
paletteExpr[]=
With[{
 functionName1DVs=DownValues[functionName1],
 functionName2DVs=DownValues[functionName2]
 },
 DynamicWrapper[
  Panel[
   Column[{paletteParts}]
   ],
  DownValues[functionName1]=functionName1DVs;
  DownValues[functionName2]=functionName2DVs
  ]
 ]


(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Generate Palette *)

(* Generate the palette and dump it to a file *)
generatePalette[]:=
 With[
  {
   nb=CreateDocument[paletteExpr[]]
   },
  closeOpenPalettesWithSameFileName[];
  NotebookSave[nb, paletteFileName[]];
  ]

(* ::Subsubsection:: *)
(* Reset Palette Builder State *)

resetState[]

EndPackage[]
```

Unfortunately, since I always use the same template, all my palettes look like this:

[image: asdasd]

But they function well and look decent, so I call it a win.