# Programmatically opening a palette from the Palettes menu

Tags: front-end, palettes

How can I programmatically open a palette from the Palettes menu?  Is there a Front End token for this?

---

Motivation:

Certain settings for the palettes that are installed into standard locations and show up in the Palettes menu [are stored in the `"PalettesMenuSettings"` global option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1113/12) (accessible through the Option Inspector or `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "PalettesMenuSettings"]`).  These settings become active only if the palette is opened through the Palettes menu.  If the palette notebook is opened directly (through the operating system's file manager or `File -> Open...`), then these settings do not take effect.

Use case:

I need to re-open the image uploader palette after it has updated itself.  The upload history is stored in the `"PalettesMenuSettings"`.

Comment: Did you check this list? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4209612/353410

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Where on earth did you find that list?  It's extremely useful!  Can you post an answer saying that `FrontEndToeknExecute["OpenFromPalettesMenu", notebookFileName]` will do it?

Comment: The links to the sources are in that very post. Glad to help :)

Comment: New and more complete list here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8606/193

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209612/353410) I posted a large stock of undocumented FE tokens.

Per your comment under the question, the required token is in that list:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenFromPalettesMenu", notebookFileName]
```

Comment: you can probably copy it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5) so that it's on our site (at least, the ones not already mentioned)

Comment: @R.M Done. It was already linked by Chris there, I just made it self contained.