# Construction of palettes

Tags: programming, palettes

Is there a good documentation to help to construct my own palettes. The problem is to use a palette as an assistant to remember some long command line with many place holder and not to be obliged to search the documentation each time I want to do a complex task.

Comment: Is there anything you want to know that was not tackled [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html)?

Comment: See also [What are the most common (usual) ways to make palettes with non-trivial functionality?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-the-most-common-usual-ways-to-make-palettes-with-non-trivial-function)

Comment: In standard packages, you have macro which can be used on hilighted text. I wondered how to do that in a palette context but in the documentation I have not found the way to do it.